# Add datepicker in jquery mobile ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I want that a calendar pop-up when any user touches or click on the input type field in jquery mobile app development.
I have tried few solutions from google but none worked.so guys can any one give the code to do that.

Thank you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery Mobile **[DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/)** plugin by JTSage. After including the library, set the input data-role to datebox and use data-options or script to control the features.

```
<input type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"calbox"}'>
```